# Accuracy goes straight for about 200 epochs then start increasing

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Can anyone explain the following observation?

Why did the accuracies keep to be a straight line with a very smooth decrease of loss?

Is this because of the learning rate or other reasons?

Some info:

The input is in the dimension of (319,50,40) as (batch, step, features)

The dataset consists of 319 samples. It was split using `train_test_split()` to yield 0.2 test size.

I used a self-attention LSTM model with 4 Dense layers and 1 self-attention LSTM layer. The codes are long, I will post them if it is needed.

The hyperparameters:

```
batch_size= 100
epochs =1400
learning_rate = 0.00014
optimizer = 'RMS'
num_classes = y_train.shape[1]
dropout=0.37
```

In addition,
If I don't set random seed and keep `shuffle=True`, Sometimes, I get a horizontal line till the endo of training without any increasing.
[image]

Comment: Well these type of questions can be best answered on datascience stack exchange, you may not find much people active on this forum.

Comment: that's strange, loss is reducing quick but accuracy stays horizontal

Comment: can you give more context? it's possible if the model is trained with different behavior after some epochs ( changing learning rate, etc.)

Comment: @malioboro No, every parameter stays the same and increasing the learning rate shorts the horizontal straight line.

Comment: how about your data validation size? if your data validation is small, it's also possible you have the same accuracy score for some epochs, please edit your post and tell us more about your data, problem, model, etc.